# How to test Android Room Transactions with Flowables and Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

**Background**

I've got the below test where I'm trying to observe (RxJava Flowable) the change in count of items in a table once inserts (coroutines/suspend) are performed in a transaction:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class Test {

    @get:Rule var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var database: Database
    private lateinit var transactionManager: TransactionManager

    @Before
    fun createDatabase() {
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
                ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
                Database::class.java
            )
            .setTransactionExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) // To avoid transaction deadlock
            .build()
    }

    @After
    fun closeDb() {
        database.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun getCountChanges_whenItemInserted_shouldUpdateCount(): Unit = runBlocking {
        
        // getCountChanges() returns Flowable<Int>
        val subscriber = database.item().getCountChanges().take(2).test()

        val callable = suspend {
            database.node().insert(NodeDO("id1")) // standard dao method marked with suspend
            database.item().insert(ItemDO("id1")) // standard dao method marked with suspend
        }
        transactionManager.runInTransaction(callable) // just calling db.withTransaction(callable)

        subscriber.assertComplete() // Test fails here - not complete ****
        subscriber.assertNoErrors()
        subscriber.assertValueCount(2)
        assertThat(subscriber.values().first()).isEqualTo(0)
        assertThat(subscriber.values().last()).isEqualTo(1)
        subscriber.dispose()
    }
}
```

**Test Results**

1. If I run the test as is, the test fails (as marked at the spot in the code above) saying that the subscriber is not complete.
2. If I remove the `.setTransactionExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` line, the test gets deadlocked and never finishes.
3. If I remove the transaction, and execute the two inserts independently, the test passes successfully.

**Question**

How can I successfully test this situation using a transaction?